# Python3 Selenium Webdriver times out during initialization

Tags: python, sockets, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

The following script(s):

```
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Firefox()
```

or

```
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
```

will very nearly always fail on my Windows 7 machine, producing the following stack trace(s):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 254, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 488, in _request
resp = self._conn.getresponse()
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1334, in getresponse
response.begin()
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 300, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 260, in _read_status
line_tmp = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

And the same for Chrome (except ...\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py, obviously). This behavior is very consistent, although on rare occasions reattempting to open a webdriver within the same Python session will allow Selenium to successfully open the browser, and (so far as I've been able to tell) operate correctly from there on out.

This behavior is not observed on my Linux machine, which is on the same network; any attempt to open a webdriver works correctly.

I'm stumped, all socket timeout issues I've found through Google have been related to attempting to access a webpage, not just creating a new webdriver object. I can provide any additional information required to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question -

While you work with `Selenium 3.4.3`, `chromedriver v2.30`, `geckodriver v0.17.0`, `Google Chrome 59.0` and `Mozilla Firefox 53.0` through `Python 3.6.1` you can consider the following options:

### Chrome :

To initialize `chromedriver` you can consider mentioning the absolute path of the `chromedriver` through **`executable_path`** argument and additionally specify/use the **`chrome_options`** argument to configure the required browser properties as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```

### Firefox :

To initialize `geckodriver` you can consider mentioning the absolute path of the `geckodriver` through **`executable_path`** argument and additionally specify/use the **`firefox_binary`** argument to configure the required browser as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: This appears to have intermittently corrected it on Firefox. Not 100% but certainly much better than before. I'd have to experiment a bit more but it seems like it must fail once, and thereafter will continue working. Chrome is not helped by these changes.